# Laravel Spatie Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::assignRole()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

Trying to do `assignRole()` to many users, but it show me Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::assignRole(). Is this spatie laravel bug?

```
$get_username = \App\Applicant::select('username')->whereIn('id', $ids);
        $updateUser = \App\User::whereIn('username', $get_username);
        $updateUser->assignRole('Applicant');
        $updateUser->save();
```

Any solution for bulk `assignRole()` in this case?

Comment: get the user from the db $updateUser = \App\User::whereIn('username', $get_username)->first();

Comment: it only assign role for one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $get_username = \App\Applicant::select('username')->whereIn('id', $ids);
> ```

This is an incomplete query via the QueryBuilder. As well as the second line.

When utilizing the QueryBuilder you need to finish of your queries with the `get()` method to get a collection to iterate over.

The correct execution would like like this:

```
$get_username = \App\Applicant::select('username')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Without knowing the exact result of this, it looks like you'd like to retrieve a collection of usernames, that you'd like to get the User model from.

You could do something like the following (untested) for bulk updating.:

```
$users = User::whereIn('username', function($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->select('username')
    ->from('applicants')->whereIn('id', $ids);
})->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->assignRole('Applicant');
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: it only assign role for one record. Beside, there is error warning. Cardinality violation 1242 subquery return more than 1 row (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = (select `username` from `applicants` where `id` in (148,149)) )

Comment: Finally work, I change to `User::whereIn`. Many thanks